# wget how to download zip files with query parameters attached to filename

Tags: linux, wget

I am sending a request to a clients server using `wget`. I want to download all the `.zip` files but the problem is the `.zip` files have key/values appended to the files. Like so:

```
http://example.com/client/photoshop-templates.zip?id=95923_324853&st=34258902386
```

The command I have used, without success is:

```
wget http://example.com/client/ -nd -r -L 1 -U="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0" --no-cache -A .zip
```

Is wget reading the filename as something other than a zip file because of the key/values appended to the files?

Comment: What errors do you get? As it stands all we know is you are trying to use wet and that is it.

Comment: Are you just trying to strip off the parameters from the destination filename? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129548/rename-file-by-removing-url-parameter-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is something like this:

```
wget -O photoshop-templates.zip http://example.com/client/photoshop-templates.zip?id=95923_324853&st=34258902386
```

or you can also try curl

```
curl -o photoshop-templates.zip http://example.com/client/photoshop-templates.zip?id=95923_324853&st=34258902386
```